# scrlayer-scrpage puts my header to offset with geometry and margin

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script, geometry, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm trying to copy the header from [koma-script-manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en). So far everything worked out fine, although I needed to use [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set my specific typearea. If I use `scrlayer-scrpage` to set my header the header magically gets an offset. Even more odd - the offset depends on the loading order of `geometry` - loaded before `scrlayer-scrpage` the offset is positive - loaded after it's negative. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?
[image: header offset with geometry and scrlayer-scrpage]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENTCLASS
\documentclass[%
    paper=a4,%
    parskip=never,% 
    fontsize=10pt% 
    ]{scrartcl}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TYPEAREA
\usepackage{geometry}%
\geometry{
left=2mm,% 
right=2mm,%
top=0mm,%
bottom=2mm,%
includehead,%
includemp,%
headsep=2mm,%
nofoot,%
marginparwidth=20mm,% 
marginparsep=2mm,%
reversemp%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLORS
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\definecolor{header-background}{RGB}{135,206,250}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HEADER/FOOTER
\usepackage[%
    automark,%
    headwidth=paper,%
    headsepline% +
    ]{scrlayer-scrpage}%
\pagestyle{scrheadings}%
\clearpairofpagestyles% 
\ihead*{Some Title}%
\ohead*{\pagemark}% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% from scrguide to color header
\DeclareLayer[clone=scrheadings.head.oneside,
contents={%
\color{header-background}%
\rule[-\dp\strutbox]%
{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}%
}%
]{scrheadings.head.oneside.background}
\DeclareLayer[clone=scrheadings.head.odd,
contents={%
\color{header-background}%
\rule[-\dp\strutbox]%
{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}%
}%
]{scrheadings.head.odd.background}
\DeclareLayer[clone=scrheadings.head.even,
contents={%
\color{header-background}%
\rule[-\dp\strutbox]%
{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}%
}%
]{scrheadings.head.even.background}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
scrheadings.head.oneside.background,%
scrheadings.head.odd.background,%
scrheadings.head.even.background%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DEBUG   
\usepackage{lipsum}% adds lipsum
\usepackage{layout}% shows layout on page
\makeatletter% layout in mm
    \renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{%
    \strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm%
    }%
\makeatother%
\KOMAoptions{%
%   draft=true% small black boxes in overfull lines
overfullrule=true% like draft - sometimes works better
}%
%   \geometry{showframe}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lipsum
\newpage
\layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load package `scrlayer-scrpage` after the layout settings by `geometry`. But you have to set the offset for the header. See the documentation to get information what happens if the offset part is missing for the `headwidth` key.

```
\usepackage[%
  automark,%
  headwidth=paper:-\the\oddsidemargin-1in,% <width>:<offset>
  headsepline%
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

or

```
\usepackage[%
  automark,%
  headsepline%
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=paper:-\oddsidemargin-1in}% <width>:<offset>
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[%
  parskip=never,%
  fontsize=10pt% 
]{scrartcl}%

\usepackage{geometry}%
\geometry{
  margin=2mm,% all margins 2mm
  top=0mm,% but top 0mm
  includehead,%
  includemp,%
  headsep=2mm,%
  nofoot,%
  marginparwidth=20mm,% 
  marginparsep=2mm,%
  reversemp%
}%

\usepackage{xcolor}%
\definecolor{header-background}{RGB}{135,206,250}

\usepackage[%
  automark,%
  headsepline%
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=paper:-\oddsidemargin-1in}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{Some Title}
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\DeclareLayer[
  clone=scrheadings.head.oneside,
  everyside,% removes restrication to oneside
  oddorevenpage,% removes restrication to oddside
  contents={%
    \color{header-background}%
    \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}%
  }
]{scrheadings.head.background}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
  scrheadings.head.background%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}%
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Additional remarks:

One definition of the background layer is enough.

For the original definition of the header in the KOMA-Script documentation have a look in the [scrguide.cls](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/source-doc/scrguide.cls).

Comment: `\the\oddsidemargin` was exactly the "unit" I was searching for @esdd